# Video Streaming application using GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I would like to create a GStreamer application for streaming video/audio over wireless network.For codec I will use H.264 .Please advice transmitting the data what should I use MPEG2-TS or RTP? I am not sure from where I should start to write the application.
I will work in c/c++ in ubuntu.Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708547/streaming-using-gstreamer/7745374#7745374

Answer (score 0):

Rtp is commonly used. You can have a look at examples under gst-plugins-good/tests/examples/rtp/.