# Streaming using GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer, rtp, live-streaming

I have got one HD video "ed_hd.avi" on System#1. Would like to stream it over network and play the content from System#2. I am using GStreamer on Ubuntu 11.04, tried a lot on this. Variety of errors makes this objective difficult to diagnose. Will be thankful for getting a working command for the System#1-end and System#2-end.

What I have tried is as follows:

System #1:

`gst-launch filesrc location=ed_hd.avi ! decodedin ! x263enc ! video/x-h264 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000`

System #2:

`gst-launch udpsrc port=5000 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! xvimagesink`

Objective is : Convert avi file to raw video. Stream it from the second System#2.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the following

```
gst-launch filesrc location=ed_hd.avi ! decodebin ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

**If that doesn't work then proceed:**

Did you try the following? You need to replace his audio bins with video bins

http://delog.wordpress.com/2011/06/01/stream-raw-vorbis-audio-over-udp-or-tcp-with-gstreamer/

Also take a look at

http://pastebin.com/PtD21Bx7

Here replace v4l2src with your video src

Also

https://metalab.at/wiki/Gstreamer_One_Liners

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the `127.0.0.1` portion. That is a *loopback* address (check `ifconfig lo0` to see the `Link encap:Local Loopback` for the `127.0.0.1` address). This won't work across *two* systems, though it might work fine on a single system.

Instead, use the address that is publicly visible for the second machine; check `ip addr show` or `ifconfig` output to find the address. Write the actual address for System #2 in the command line on System #1.

Comment: In your example you mix H263 and H264.  Ditto the previous comment about 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @Wes, you might wish to comment directly on deltasumo's question -- I didn't mention h263 nor h264...