# Setting up MJPEG compressor

Tags: filter, directshow, video-encoding, renderer, mjpeg

I made a console program that previews a video from webcam and captures it throught the MJPEG compression filter to .avi format. My schema:

```
WebCam
->IBaseFilter(Video capture filter)
 ->IBaseFilter(MJPEG compression filter)
  ------------->ICaptureGraphBuilder2::RenderStream
                ->.avi
```

1. Any advice on how to set up MJPEG compression parameters via IAMVideoCompression interface to get the smallest video size and at least average quality? For now I set the putQuality method parameter to 0.1 and it helps me a lot; my video file size is about 15mb/minute.
2. I can't render this captured .avi file with any video players (I tried Windows Media Player, WMP Classic, VLC). Do I need to make a decompressor before I can watch this video?
3. Is there another compression filter I should be using? Which one is the best?

My aim is to write a video streaming server (like Skype). Do you think 15mb/minute is a good size to transfer the video packets down the network? I am going to use UDP(RTP) socket to transfer the mediastream.

Comment: nice question! i will look for answers too

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Gstreamer.

An example pipeline to decode an MJPEG stream would be

```
gst-launch -v souphttpsrc location="http://[ip]:[port]/[dir]/xxx.cgi" do-timestamp=true is_live=true ! multipartdemux ! jpegdec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

To save it to a file instead

```
gst-launch -v souphttpsrc location="http://[ip]:[port]/[dir]/xxx.cgi" do-timestamp=true is_live=true ! multipartdemux ! jpegdec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! filesink location=test.avi
```

To get video from webcam and save it (tested on Ubuntu Linux)

```
gst-launch v4l2src ! jpegdec ! filesink location=test.avi
```

jpegdec is a bin to decode jpeg format that contains "idct-method" for the quality

You can write the above pipelines in equivalent C/C++, Java or Python code. It has pretty nice bindings.

For programming look at my other post

[Playing RTSP with python-gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192871/playing-rtsp-with-python-gstreamer/6819360#6819360)

For network related stuff you may want to look at RTSP(UDP based RTP) look at my answer to the post here

[Streaming using GStreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708547/streaming-using-gstreamer/7745374#7745374)